# TypeError: google.maps.geometry is undefined (Ivory Google Maps Bundle)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, symfony

So I have a controller with a function that creates a Google Map, puts a marker on the $from and $to places (if both defined), and draws a route in between. This function is used in two ways:
- embedded controller in twig, where $from and $to are given variables
- ajax call, where $from and $to are passed in the request.

The problem is that this works great with the embedded controller, but when used in an ajax call I get the above error.

Some code samples:
From the controller:

```
public function stageMapAction(Request $request, $from = null, $to = null)
{
    if($from === null){
        $from = $request->query->get('from');
    }
    if($to === null){
        $to = $request->query->get('to');
    }

    .......(create map, put markers on it, code omitted) ....

    if($from !='' && $to!='' ){
        $temp = $directions->route($from, $to);
        $routes = $temp->getRoutes();
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $overviewPolyline = $route->getOverviewPolyline();
            $overviewPolyline->setOption('strokeColor', '#0000ff');
            $overviewPolyline->setOption('strokeWeight', 1.5);
            $map->addEncodedPolyline($overviewPolyline);
        }
    }
```

From the twig template where a record is displayed:

```
{% set from = stagecurrent.getStageFrom() %}
{% set to = stagecurrent.getStageTo() %}
{{ render(controller('TravelBundle:Map:stageMap',{ 'from':from, 'to':to })) }}
```

From the jquery where I display the same stuff on a form (the map_stage_call route calls the same controller and function):

```
function refreshMap(){
    var $from = $('.stage-from').val();
    var $to = $('.stage-to').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url('map_stage_call') }}?from=" + $from + "&to=" + $to,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#placeholder-map').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#placeholder-map').html('error');
        }
    });
};
```

Weird is that everything works well when I just place the markers, it is the polyline that seems to give the problem. Even stranger is that when I pass the $from and $to to the output html, they are exactly the same in both cases. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you [load the geometry-library](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#configure-additional-libraries)?

Comment: Not really, but when i call the function directly from Twig it works. Calling the same from Ajax doesnt work. Suppose that loading the lib would either be needed by both methods, or not at all?